# Android. Send Table with Json

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBROp.png)

Lets say I have this table.

I want to send all the data to a MySql extenal Database so I can read it on a Php site showing the same table, or the USER and its items and values.

First I was using Volley library and putting Strings inside the HashMap like this:

```
   @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    hashMap.put("user", "name");
                    hashMap.put("address", "address");
                    hashMap.put("phone", "phone");
                    hashMap.put("item", "item 1");
                    hashMap.put("obs", "na");
                    hashMap.put("pay", "cash");
                    hashMap.put("value","R$ 49,90");
                    hashMap.put("idCompany", "1");


                    return hashMap;
                }
            };

            requestQueue.add(request);
```

But doesnt seem to be the right thing to use for what I want.

Whats the best way of doing it?

UPDATE....

Sooo I tried to get a JsonString from the DataBase.

```
 public JSONObject enviarCarrinho() {

    Cursor c;
    db = banco.getReadableDatabase();
    String h = "SELECT * FROM CARRINHO";
    c = (db.rawQuery(h, null));

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject jsonObjectInner = new JSONObject();

    if (c!= null && c.getCount() > 0) {
        c.moveToFirst();

    try {
        do{
            jsonObjectInner.put("CARRINHO_ID", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CARRINHO_ID")));
            jsonObjectInner.put("CARRINHO_ITEM", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CARRINHO_ITEM")));
            jsonObjectInner.put("CARRINHO_OBSERVACAO", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CARRINHO_OBSERVACAO")));
            jsonObjectInner.put("CARRINHO_QUANTIDADE",c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CARRINHO_QUANTIDADE")));
            jsonObjectInner.put("CARRINHO_VALOR", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CARRINHO_VALOR")));
            jsonObject.put("carrinho", jsonObjectInner);
        }while(c.moveToNext());

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    return jsonObject;
}
```

And Send it via Post

```
 @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    JSONObject jsonObject =  db.enviarCarrinho();
                    hashMap.put("itenspedido", String.valueOf(jsonObject));
                    hashMap.put("nomecliente", "kelen");
                    hashMap.put("enderecocliente", "endereco cliente");
                    hashMap.put("telefonecliente", "telefone indiciduo");
                    hashMap.put("valor", "1000000");
                    hashMap.put("idrestaurante", "1");


                    return hashMap;
                }
            };

            requestQueue.add(request);
```

Its Working to get and Json and send it. Problem is that its only returning the last row from the table. Any thoughts how to resolve it??

Comment: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/itensphp-png this is the result I will need on my php site.

Comment: Are able to achieve your result  using Volley .